# OCMock is only effective once, strange, why? Or what's wrong on my side?

Tags: ocmock

I want to do mock for TnSettings, yes, it works if code by the following method, the problem is that we need to do write mock code for each case, if we only mock once then execute more than one case, then the second will report exception. I use the latest OCMock V2.01.

My question is that why OCMock has such restriction? Or is it my fault not to use it correctly?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
- (void) testFormattedDistanceValueWithMeters {         
        mockSettings = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TnSettings class]];
        mockClientModel = [TnClientModel createMockClientModel];
        [[[mockClientModel expect] andReturn:mockSettings] settings];
        [[[mockSettings expect] andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] preferencesGeneralUnits];

        NSNumber *meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.9];
        distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
        STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"0.9", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");

        //------------- Another case -----------------
        mockSettings = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TnSettings class]];
        mockClientModel = [TnClientModel createMockClientModel];
        [[[mockClientModel expect] andReturn:mockSettings] settings];
        [[[mockSettings expect] andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] preferencesGeneralUnits];

        meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100.9];
        distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
        STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"101", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question or your code fully. I suspect that you stumbled over the difference between *expect* and *stub*, though.

Is this what you had in mind?

```
- (void) testFormattedDistanceValueWithMeters {         
    mockSettings = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TnSettings class]];
    mockClientModel = [TnClientModel createMockClientModel];
    [[[mockClientModel stub] andReturn:mockSettings] settings];
    [[[mockSettings stub] andReturn:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] preferencesGeneralUnits];

    NSNumber *meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.9];
    distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
    STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"0.9", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");

    meters = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100.9];
    distance = [NSString formattedDistanceValueWithMeters:meters];
    STAssertEqualObjects(distance, @"101", @"testformattedEndTimeForTimeInSeconds failed");
```

}

Comment: Thank you, you are right, change [mockSettings expect] to [mockSettings stub] then my problem has been resolved. Plus one question, why use expect it will throw exception on the 2nd round invoking? Is it OCNock bug?

Comment: When you use expect then you are specifying the precise contract. If you want to say that the method should be called twice then you would have to call expect twice. Other mock frameworks provide convenience methods to achieve this. One day I'll add that to OCMock, too, somehow like [[[mockSettings expect] times:2] someMethod].